# Go to a path if current url has specific flags in url

Tags: jquery

I need to use jquery to redirect a user to a new url if they land on a url that contains specific arguments.

So when a user lands on `www.thisurl.com/property#yes?uid=12&fid=3` I want to then redirect them to `www.thaturl.com/fill?fid=3&uid=12`

If the `#yes` shows up in the url they land on initially, then redirect them and include all of the other flags in the initial url, if not, then keep them where they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the hash, see if it matches, and then forward the request.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;

if (hash && hash.substr(1, 3) == 'yes') {
   window.location = 'http://www.thaturl.com/fill' + hash.substr(4);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WWce/).